# How can I avoid overflowing the water pan while defrosting my fridge?

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Samsung manual defrost refrigerator. Usually after a month's running ice builds up a lot. So I just defrost, but after doing so the water pan overflows a lot. Is there any way in which the drain can be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option, defrost more often. If enough ice is collecting to overflow the pan, then simply allowing less of it to accumulate is the obvious solution. Of course that requires emptying the fridge more often as well.

Another option is just like Kevin said; put something absorbent in the drain pan so the water won't slosh or overflow as easily.

Third option; modify the drain pan to allow a drain tube, that you can feed into whatever catchment you want. This would require the tube to be installed when you wanted to defrost, or else you'd have to fashion a plug or stopper.

Answer (score 3):

Our fridge's auto defrost when out and we had a solid chunk of thick ice that we had to manually defrost before the repair man could do anything, he suggested we put quite a few towels in the freezer as well as the fridge  part. it soaked up pretty much all the water from the melted ice and we got our fridge fixed a couple days later. maybe put some towels in the fridge and under your pan. it'll make LESS of a mess anyways ;). Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks this is a good suggestion. I will defrost once in a week.

Comment: Check the door seals and make sure they are tight fitting.If you have to defrost that often either the door is being opened quite often or house air is infiltrating into the fridge.c